# How to display a p:graphicImage after clicking an h:commandButton

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I am having a run button with action as an execution called from mybean. Once button executed running gif should display.
Which action should trigger the running.gif to be  displayed?

Here is my code

```
<h:commandButton value="Run" action="#{mybean.execute()}" class="btn btn-success btnWidth" style="margin-left:15px;margin-right:15px;"/>

 <p:graphicImage url="/resources/icons/running.gif" height="20" width="20" />
```

Comment: How would you do this in plain html? Try the same here.

Comment: I had this in xhtml page.I just copied only these lines as logic required based on these 2 lines.

Comment: Clear, but not related in anyway to what I stated. With just this piece of code, jsf is merely an html generator. Look at the generated html. It is fairly simple. Look how you would display (and initially hide?) the gif. And extrapolate to jsf. But you'll most like;y run into issues and there are better solutions. Inspect the PrimeFaces showcase (hint: you most likely need ajax)